# Image, pdf attachment into couchbase and read blob file type and regenerate the file from couchbase

Tags: python-3.x, couchbase

I am new in couchbase. I want to save image as blob into couchbase db and read the couchbase blob and regenerate file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forget one thing my code base in python 3.7, I am using python sdk

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase is often considered a document database because of how it can handle JSON, but it also can be used as a regular key/value store (i.e. it's a ["multimodal" database](https://medium.com/@couchbase/why-your-nosql-database-should-be-multimodal-3fc096f83261)). You can store anything as a value, including bytes, utf-8, etc.

There is an example on how to [store non-JSON data in Couchbase](https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/current/nonjson.html) in the Couchbase docs.

I'm not a Python dev, but here's an example from the docs using the "raw" format:

```
>>> from couchbase import FMT_BYTES
>>> cb.upsert('utf16_doc',
              'Hello, UTF-16 World!'.encode('utf16'),
              format=FMT_BYTES)
```

In the above example, you would replace `'Hello, UTF-16 World!'.encode('utf16')` with the byte array of your PDF file, and in Python `FMT_BYTES` is how you specify "raw".

Alternatively, you can encode a PDF attachment into base64, and store that in JSON. For instance:

```
{
  "filename": "Anupam.pdf",
  "format": "application/pdf",
  "blobBase64": "JVBERi0xLjMKJf////8KMSAwIG9iago8PCAvQ3JlYXRvciAoUHJhd24pCi9Qcm9kd..."
}
```

Generally speaking, I'd be careful about storing binary data in Couchbase. Couchbase values have a [size limit of 20 MB](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/clusters-and-availability/size-limitations.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply. In case of image it saved as "file_data":{"@type":"blob","content_type":"image/jpeg","digest":"sha1-2dfdsfklkdflskdklkd/sdfdf=","length":11789}.  How can I regenerate the image file from this information of couchbase.

Comment: If that's the entire document, I don't think you can regenerate the file. Are you sure it's not stored in a file system somewhere? This just looks like metadata